# Azure CDN content takes time to refresh

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-cdn

I'm using Azure CLI to purge the contents from Azure CDN endpoint. I got a reference from Microsoft Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/cdn/endpoint?view=azure-cli-latest

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-purge-endpoint

I use the following command to refresh specific png file as shown below:

***az cdn endpoint purge -g cdnRG --profile-name cdnprofile2 --content-paths "/img/cdn.png" --name cdnprofileendpoint2***

Command executed successfully, though surprised that content is not refreshing or sometime it takes time.
is it the acceptable pattern?
Kindly advise.

Comment: Are you doing a hard refresh with your browser? The contents of the cdn are likely being cached by your browser.

Comment: @technogeek1995 Yes, Browser caches teh content so I've also tried with incognito window, however no fruitful result.

Answer (score 3):

Since purging an Azure CDN endpoint only clears the cached content on the CDN edge servers. Any downstream caches, such as **proxy servers and local browser caches**, may still hold a cached copy of the file. You can force a downstream client to request the latest version of your file by giving it **a unique name every time you update it**, or by taking advantage of [query string caching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-query-string).

I suggest [purging the same path contents in the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-purge-endpoint#walkthrough) comparing to purge it with Azure CLI command. You also try to [purge CDN endpoint with Azure Powershell](https://www.codeisahighway.com/howto-purge-an-azure-cdn-endpoint-using-azure-powershell-v1-x/).

The important thing is that the CDN provider takes influence on the purging time.

> Purge requests take approximately 10 minutes to process with Azure CDN
> from Microsoft, approximately 2 minutes with Azure CDN from Verizon
> (standard and premium), and approximately 10 seconds with Azure CDN
> from Akamai. Azure CDN has a limit of 50 concurrent purge requests at
> any given time at the profile level.

Comment: Many Thanks its quite informative with respect to with the option you have choosen.Though i have used the following having wild character using azure CLI ,az cdn endpoint purge -g appsvc_windows_centralus --profile-name staticCDN --content-paths '/img/cdn.png' --name cdnstatic                                                                                                                           
 az cdn endpoint purge -g appsvc_windows_centralus --profile-name staticCDN --content-paths '/*' --name cdnstatic

Comment: Do you still have any question about this? what CDN provider do you have? you can validate this via purge it on the portal or purge it on az CLI to compare the result.

Comment: I've tried with both Akamai and Microsoft and purged some specific images using azure CLI after usin az login.Though i've observed that Microsoft's one doesn't take much time.Many Thanks :)